# How to convert an addition as a string into an integer

Tags: swift

I have a variable as a string `let q1 = "3 + 5"` but I want to convert into an integer so that `let q1 = 8`. I tried using `let q1Int: Int? = Int(q1)`but it doesn't seem to equal 8. I need to keep q1 as a string at first because I need to display "3 + 5" on the screen.

```
let q1 = "3 + 5"
var questionInt: Int? = Int(q1)
var answerInt: Int? = Int(answer)
if answerInt == questionInt{

      addScore()

}
```

When I change `questionInt` to 8 it adds to the score but when I try by converting the string to an integer it doesn't.

Comment: How do you get the strings as "3 + 5"?

Comment: I have an array of question and one of the questions in the array is "3 + 5". The code picks a question at random. The question I am using as an example is `let q1 = " 3 + 5"`. The question will be displayed on the screen as an SKLabelNode. They then type in the answer and when they press enter on screen it compares their answer `var answerInt` to the answer of `let q1 = "3 +5'`. I want to make it so the code converts q1 into an integer and does 3 + 5 then compares there answer to the answer of "3 + 5". I hope this answers your question, I am really bad at explaining.

Comment: Check if the duplicate solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it did must have been researching the wrong thing, thanks